# WHERE NOT EXIST not working (Data gets duplicated!!!)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I am adding user data from a table to another for a Wordpress's plugin

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_bp_xprofile_data (user_id, field_id, value)
        SELECT ID, '7', cedula
FROM employees

WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data
                 WHERE (ID=user_id AND
                       '7'=field_id AND
                        cedula=value
                       )
                 )
```

The Query runs fine, but when ran a second/third... time, it **duplicates** all the data I'm pulling from the employees table into xprofile. With the 'Where Not Exists' I want each employee data to be added **only once if it doesn't exist already**.

This is weird and can't really figure out what's wrong, even in an early query for another table, it doesn't duplicate the employees and works right, here I'm pulling data from wp_users into wp_usermeta:

```
    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
        SELECT ID, 'first_name', SUBSTRING_INDEX(display_name, ' ', 1)
FROM wp_users

WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM wp_usermeta
                 WHERE (ID=user_id AND
                       'first_name'=meta_key AND
                       SUBSTRING_INDEX(display_name, ' ', 1)=meta_value 
                       )
                 )
```

On this one, it won't duplicate the records when ran again if the records are already in, if anyone can see what's wrong, your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, just figured it out, both employees and wp_bp_xprofile_data tables have an 'ID' column, and my query in WHERE was not being specific to which ID restrict. Now works with:

```
INSERT INTO wp_bp_xprofile_data (user_id, field_id, value)
        SELECT ID, '7', cedula
FROM employees

WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data
                 WHERE (employees.ID=user_id AND
                       '7'=field_id AND
                        cedula=value
                       )
                 )
```